# ng-repeat value as ng-class for last <td>

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-class

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in rows">
    <td ng-class="{row[th]:$last}" ng-repeat="th in ths">{{row[th]}}</td>
</tr>
```

for the code above, i'm trying to use the **row[th]** value as the name of the class in **ng-class** for the **last td element only**.
I can use an actual class name just fine, but not the referenced value from row[th]. Any ideas how to accomplish this?

PS: the row[th] will return a status (e.g. Red, Green, etc.), which is also a css class name i'm using.

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/snn5/wmfbczm2/25/)

in the fiddle above, if i replace **row[th]** with **Green** in ng-class, that works!

---

the solution below by @tasseKATT works fine, however now i seem to have another issue. i'm not able to include another static-named class. Fiddle [link here](http://jsfiddle.net/snn5/wmfbczm2/27/). Any help much appreciated.

Comment: could you provide a sample for  `rows`?

Comment: Can you set up a plunker/jsfiddle/code snippet to demonstrate the issue? what is the value of `th`? is it a valid index/key on your repeater, because if its not then it would just be failing silently.

Comment: @DonJuwe, fiddle link added. Plz see edits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much troubleshooting, I came up with the following solution (extending @tasseKATT's original answer:

```
<td ng-class="{true: [row[th], 'staticCSSClassName']}[$last]" ng-repeat="th in ths">{{row[th]}}</td>
```

The code above adds two classes to the **last <td>** in **ng-repeat**:

1. **value** contained in **row[th]**
2. staticCSSClassName

So, basically, the **value** part in the **Object** can be an array of strings, which can include referenced values from **ng-repeat** as well as static class names.

[working jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/snn5/wmfbczm2/29/)

Hope someone finds this useful.